# Install pipenv using brew on Python 3.6

Tags: python, homebrew, pipenv

I am trying to install pipenv using Homebrew as suggested in [here](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#installing-pipenv).

First, I ran `$ brew install pipenv`. Then, brew install python 3.7 automatically and I can use pipenv properly. But, I want to use pipenv on Python 3.6, so I ran `$ brew switch python 3.7 3.6.5` and then when I tried `$ pipenv install` an error appeared as follow:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.11.26/libexec/bin/python3.7
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Is there any solution to install pipenv along with Python 3.6.5?

Thank you.

Comment: You can always install using your specific Python using pip

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and spent a long time researching. In the end I determined my project did not absolutely need `python3.6` so I switched brew to `python3.7` and reinstalled `pipenv`.

If you absolutely need to use `pipenv` with `python3.6` then you may find [this thread](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2965) helpful but to me it seemed like a nuclear option I didn't want to go through.

How to move back to using `pipenv` with `python3.7`:

```
# get your version of python3.7
brew list --versions python

# switch to your python3.7 version
brew switch python 3.7.x_x 

# install pipenv if it was removed during the troubleshooting process
brew install pipenv

# pipenv should work now
pipenv --help
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, but first install python 3.6.5

```
pipenv --python 3.6.5
```

Comment: This was the only solution that worked with me , my case was "pipenv install" raising the same above error, it seems pipeline was targeting the wrong python framework

Answer (score 1):

You can always install using your specific Python using pip:

```
python3 -m pip install --user pipenv
```

python3, here assumes your 3.6.5, if not then use the whole path to your desired Python.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2965

Make sure you're using python3.6

```
$ python
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jun 17 2018, 12:13:06)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>

$ brew switch python # if not, see your versions
Error: Usage: brew switch <formula> <version>
python installed versions: 3.6.5_1, 3.7.3

$ brew switch python 3.6.5_1 # change your version if is necessary
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1
Cleaning /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3
25 links created for /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1
```

Install pipenv 2018.6.25

```
$ brew unlink pipenv
$ brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/2c0bbfa297e2429cd6e080ad5231f3aa56ff4f65/Formula/pipenv.rb
```

Change to pipenv 2018.6.25

```
$ brew switch pipenv 2018.6.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue after upgrading OSX version.

Solved by uninstalling homebrew installation and following the ["Pragmatic Installation" instructions](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/install/#pragmatic-installation-of-pipenv):

```
brew uninstall pipenv
pip install --user pipenv
```

If you get `pipenv: command not found`, add the user base’s binary directory to your PATH per the instructions, for OSX add this to your ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/.local/bin:$PATH
```